# Laravel Multi Database Connection Join table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, dbconnection

Datebase 1 = db1
Database 2 = db2

I have two databases connection, I wanted to run a eloquent or DB which joining connection1 and connection 2 table(db1.users and db2.users), and check connection1 id = connection 2 or not.

can someone guide me how to do that?

Appreciate that if someone could guide me what to do.

db1 user
id
name
ori_id

db2 ori_user
id
name

select db2.ori_user.name from db1.user join db1.user on db1.user.ori_id = db2.ori_user.id

Comment: yes, i can see. Is that any where can join two table from different database?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible as long as they are on the same server, for example:

```
$result = \DB::table('db1.users')
    ->join('db2.users', 'db2.users.id', '=', 'db1.users.id')
    ->select('db1.users.id as db1_id', 'db1.users.email as db1_email', 'db2.users.*')
    ->get();
```

Make sure the user has access/privilege to use both databases.

Comment: OP is asking for two separate databases.

Comment: Yes, I'm concerned about that and answered that exactly. Have you even checked my answer or you didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

in **database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'customers'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'customers2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

here **customers** is **database1** and **customers2** is **database2**

in **controller**

```
 $data=DB::select('select customers2.ori_user.name from customers.user join customers2.ori_user on customers.user.ori_id = customers2.ori_user.id');
```

or

```
$data=DB::select('your_query');
```

Youtube link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgl3FzqP1Ps&feature=youtu.be

Comment: this is just join two same database tables, is that possible to make it join from different database table.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake i thought 2 table in same database..ok i will try if i can i will provide u

Comment: thanks for your fast response, i have tried this, is not working. do you have others way?

Comment: what is the error you r getting?? can kindly share??

Comment: you may check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgl3FzqP1Ps&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Hi Borna, thanks for your help, but i still getting error. my first sql is my localhost sql, and another one is from other server. Both is working on printing individually, but they way u show me is not working for me, do i need to do other setting?

Comment: no there is no other setting... what is your another server??

Comment: can you take a screen shot of your error and post here??